# How to calculate the sum of prices (array) per time interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of date and price pairs, like the following:

```
[
    [1518371928, 15440000],
    [1518371928, 15440000],
    [1518371928, 15440000],
    [1518371928, 15440000],
    [1518371928, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518294600, 15440000],
    [1518417005, 15430000],
    [1518417005, 15430000],
    [1518420449, 15465000],
    [1518422229, 15510000],
    [1518423849, 15535000],
    [1518425806, 15598000],
    [1518427146, 15615000],
    [1518428229, 15625000],
    [1518430648, 15635000]
]
```

The first element in the sub arrays is a unix timestamp and second is a price.

Now I look for a JavaScript function that calculates the sum of prices in different time periods.

For example, when I want to calculate the hourly prices, the function should return a compact array providing the sum of prices in each hour.

Comment: And how have you tried to solve the problem so far ? Any attempts made yet ?

Comment: So in your description the line "Now I wanna JavaScript function calculate sum of price at different time periods." is unclear to me.  Are you asking for us to use the Unix time stamp times to provide the sum only up until the point of another Unix time stamp passed to a function?

Comment: in fact i get this data from another rest-api service and data is show me last price of stock at time, i save data every 15 minutes in DB and for drowning chart (candle stick chart).

Comment: That does not address any of the questions above...

Comment: for drowning candle stick chart should i pass 6 parameter to highchart library (date, price, open-price, close-price, min-price, high-price)

Comment: So then why do you need to *sum*? In which format you need the date in the output? Where is your code? What is the problem with it?

Comment: Ok I sort of understand what you are trying to do now.  Can you put what you have up so far?  I'm sure we'll be able to help figure out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need several measures per grouped item: minimum price, maximum price, first price, last price, ... I don't quite understand what the purpose could be of a *summed* price, but anyway it is doable.

Here is a function that creates an ES6 Map keyed by the unix timestamp that denotes the starting time of the group (e.g. of the hour, if it's hourly), and stores the array of prices that belong to that group.

Then from those arrays of prices per group the final indicators (min, max, first, ...) are calculated.

See this snippet:

```js
function groupByInterval(data, secondsPerGroup) {
    // First sort by the time stamps in ascending order
    data = data.sort( ([a], [b]) => a - b )
        // Then add the starting time stamps of the groups
        .map(([unix, price]) => ({ unixstart: unix - unix % secondsPerGroup, price }) );
    // Create an entry per group; initialise values as empty arrays (for prices)    
    const map = new Map(data.map( ({unixstart}) => [unixstart, []] ));
    return Array.from(
        // Collect the prices per group
        data.reduce( (acc, {unixstart, price}) => 
            acc.set(unixstart, acc.get(unixstart).concat(price)),
            map
        ).entries(),
        // Enrich the group values with formatted dates and price measures
        ([unixstart, prices]) => ({
            unixstart,
            start: new Date(unixstart * 1000).toJSON(), 
            end:   new Date((unixstart + secondsPerGroup) * 1000).toJSON(),
            minPrice: Math.min(...prices),
            maxPrice: Math.max(...prices),
            firstPrice: prices[0],
            lastPrice: prices[prices.length-1],
            countPrices: prices.length,
            sumPrices: prices.reduce( (a,b) => a+b, 0 )
        })
    );
}

// Sample input
const data = [[1518371928, 15440000],[1518371928, 15440000],[1518371928, 15440000],[1518371928, 15440000],[1518371928, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518294600, 15440000],[1518417005, 15430000],[1518417005, 15430000],[1518420449, 15465000],[1518422229, 15510000],[1518423849, 15535000],[1518425806, 15598000],[1518427146, 15615000],[1518428229, 15625000],[1518430648, 15635000]];

const result = groupByInterval(data, 60*60); // Group per hour (expressed in seconds)

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: excuse me @trincot , could you see this code?
what's my fault?

Comment: You should not wrap the result in an array, as it is already an array. Just do `const res = items;` or just work with `items` directly. NB: I had to change `https` with `http` to make the URL work.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want the price after a period of time use setTimeInterval method.

Comment: I think he already has figured out how to retrieve the data.  I think he is having problems processing the data after he got the data.